# How to clone a stage but have a link to artifact in azure dev ops 2019

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-releases

Is there any way that I can Clone my DEV stage and connect it to the Artifacts in Azure Devops 2019?
Please see the below picture. I would like to connect **Copy OF DEV** stage which I cloned from **DEV** to Artifact.
I can only create a completely brand new stage and connect it to the Artifact.But I do not want to recreate all my 34 tasks in this stage again I want to Clone from DEV.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just need to edit `Pre-deployment conditions`

[image]

and then

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!